# Open file with Python DirSelector

Tags: python, wxpython, filedialog

is it somehow possible to open a file (instead of a directory) with Python's DirSelector. It's also fine to make a wx.FileSelector to open also a directory.

I just need one dialog window to open both, files and directories.

Comment: Why don't you just use `wx.FileSelector`? You just said it works.

Comment: FileSelector allows to open file, but not directory. I need one dialog window that can be used for both - to open file and directory.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the wx.GenericDirCtrl for this, although it's a little ugly. There's also the pure python MultiDirDialog widget which can be found in wx.lib.agw.multidirdialog. While it doesn't appear to support the display and selection of files now, since it's pure Python, you can probably hack it.