# How do I allow a user to select a file?

Tags: python, r

Right now, I have this line in my code to hard-code the directory path

```
dir_path = '/home/user/pywork'
```

but I would rather let the user select it herself using a construct similar to R's `scan(choose.files())`.

How do I go about it?

Thanks,

Comment: asking directory path using a dialog box requires GUI programming.
If your application runs in terminal you can use raw_input function.

Comment: can you who me how to this this with raw_input, i'm still fairly ignorant in matters Python. take into account that i'm inexcusably work on windows.

Comment: dir_path = raw_input("Enter directory path: ") - this will ask the user to enter directory path and the entered path will be saved in dir_path variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option I found after a quick google (`python open directory dialog box`) is to use `TKinter`:

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog
root = Tkinter.Tk()
dirname = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=root, initialdir="/",
                                    title='Please select a directory')
```

I found the information [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/210657/open-directory-dialog-box).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430272/open-file-with-python-dirselector

Comment: thanks a lot, it will probably solve the issue, i still have to figure out how to implement on python32, since i understand some things have changed. thanks for the useful info!

Comment: This is the only solution I know of for users who have CLI phobia - but is there any lighter weight version to include for a 10 line script when compiling? Most of my scripts are 40 lines or less but become 11MB when adding the one line for a user to select a file.

Comment: You can use `raw_input`, for more details see the comments to the question.

Comment: it fails with Tkinter but seems to work with tkinter ... also the dialog no longer works:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#module-tkinter.filedialog